# Write from remote to remote

Tags: git

We have two hosts, `A` and `B`. `A` can connect to `B` via SSH, but `B` cannot access hosts outside its local network. We don't have root access on `B` and our home directory on `B` is periodically purged. The Internet connection from `A` to `B` is very slow.

```
    30kB/s
A ----------> B
```

On `B` we want to run and compile source code of total size ~50MB stored in a git repository. The commits are small and a single update of source code would not involve more than 30kB of diffs.

Is it possible to somehow keep the repository on `B` up-to-date in a fully automatic way (on demand)? This would be logically something like using the remote filesystem as the target directory.

We may not assume that the state of the local repository on `A` is up-to-date and it may be dirty, i.e. git may not accept a pull.

Comment: "our home directory on B is periodically purged" what?

Comment: @Pockets I'd say it's a demo VPS or something similar, where home directories aren't permanent but are left for a reduced amount of time, then the whole machine gets refreshed. If that's not the case, it's something really near to it

Comment: That's a computing node.